# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException on timeout

Tags: java

Is it possible to get `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` on `notifyAll()` because `wait(timeout)` has passed the timeout time?
If not, what happens when `notifyAll()` occurs after the timeout time has passed?
Both `notifyAll()` and `wait(timeout)` are blocked inside a synchronized block on the same locked object.

```
synchronized(lockObj) {
    lockObj.notifyAll();
}
```

And:

```
synchronized(lockObj) {
    lockObj.wait(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't get an exception for that. If you call `notifyAll` when nothing is waiting, nothing happens basically. It's not an error condition.

Comment: So if both methods are inside synchronized blocks on the same object, what other reasons can cause the IllegalMonitorStateException?

Comment: @Aya1: Something changing the value of `lockObj` between entering the synchronized block and calling the method? If you're experiencing this exception, you should try to reproduce it in a short but complete program if at all possible - then we'll be in a better position to help to explain it.

Comment: OK, so the following might not look that logical, but this is the way the application is built today: the locking object is an object that has members. It is possible that while the application is in the block of the notifyAll(), somewhere else the code sets a value into one of the members of the locking object. Will this mean that the notifyAll() will no longer be locked?

Comment: btw, hashCode() and equals() are not implemented for that locking object.

Comment: @Aya1: No, that doesn't affect things at all. It would be changing the value of the `lockObj` to be a reference to a different object that could cause this to fail.

Comment: I want to make sure that I understood you right: setting the member is the reason the lock fails, and implementing the hashCode() and equals() will not solve the problem?

Comment: @Aya1: I don't know what you mean by "the member" here - I'm saying that if somewhere you have `lockObj = someOtherValue;`, that means you could be calling `notifyAll` on an object you don't have the monitor for. Lock variables like this should almost always be `final`.